# LaTeX Annotations in Mendeley

Tags: annotations, mendeley

I am using Mendeley to read and annotate research papers. Is there any way to make annotations of mathematical content using LaTex? That is, I want to write an annotation on the paper with mathematical symbols and not just leave the annotations as \sum u_n, for example.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking if there is a way to render latex in Mendeley's annotation?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm asking @BHos